# How to apply Theme for my website?

Tags: asp.net

I want to apply theme for my website. i am using asp.net.
I think there is some easy way in asp.net.using skin files and style sheet.
can u suggest me a method or an example.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that have some info:

- [ASP.NET Master Pages Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Themes and Skins Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)

The general idea is that with a master page you can create a "layout" file that is used by multiple content pages. This will determine the overall look, feel, and "shape" of the site.

You can then use Themes and Skins to determine the precise look of particular controls, such as a Button, DropDownList, or GridView.